# Lua ignore Escape Sequence

Tags: lua, escaping, string-literals

Currently Lua has the following Escape Sequences:

- `\a`: Bell
- `\b`: Backspace
- `\f`: Form feed
- `\n`: Newline
- `\r`: Carriage return
- `\t`: Tab
- `\v`: Vertical tab
- `\\`: Backslash
- `\"`: Double quote
- `\'`: Single quote
- `\nnn`: Octal value (nnn is 3 octal digits)
- `\xNN`: Hex value (Lua5.2/LuaJIT, NN is two hex digits)

How could I use a string such as `"\a\f\\\""` ignoring all these escape sequences, interpreting it literally so to speak?

Comment: What do you mean "use a string"? What are you trying to do? `[[...]]` strings do not interpret any escape sequences.

Comment: Basically
`function checkword (instr)<
wordlist = {"FIN", "FFI", "PHIN", "PHEN", "FIN", "PHIN", "IFFUM", "MUF", "MEUFEEN", "FEN","FEEN"}
for i, v in ipairs (wordlist) do
  if (string.match(processstring(instr), v) ~= nil)then
    return 1
    end
  end
end`

Comment: Which part of that wants to ignore escape sequences? The only part there were you don't have an already lua processed string is in `wordlist`. So you can avoid them in wordlist but `instr` already has them interpreted once your function gets them. What are you trying to do here exactly? Ignore the escaped bytes in terms of checking for known/bad words (to avoid attempts to "trick" your check)?

Comment: Lua does not have octal escape sequences, \nnn escapes are decimal.

Comment: Etan, If I have a string like `"/\/\ |_| |= |= | |\|"` in wordlist it just doesn't work; not sure why.

Comment: @Arengorn Show your code that doesn't work, with [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @YuHao my bad, this is my current code https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/b89d942519d71885909f#file-muffinkicker

If you use that string I mentioned previously as the one being passed to checkword() and processstring() you can replicate the bug. Or simply by adding it to the wordlist variable.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just had this turn up in a search and noticed that your escape code reference list contains an error: \nnn is not octal in lua, it is decimal. You may have been thinking of the C-style languages, where you could type "\040" to get an ascii space, 40 octal being 32 decimal, but in lua that produces a left parenthesis because it's interpreted as decimal 40.

Comment: How is it possible to escape { } curly brackets?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Lua's *long brackets*, also called *bracketed form*, e.g. `[[\a\f\\]]`

Look here under Escape Sequences:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial

You might also be able to do something with `string.format` and `%q`, but I don't remember how that will result off the top of my head. I think it presents the string in a format suitable to be valid Lua.

Also, as noted in other comments, the C escape sequence for octals, `\nnn`, is **not** present in Lua, and can easily be confused with Lua's `\ddd` escape sequence which expects *decimal* digits.

The following reference images were taken from the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1).

[image: Lua's subset of C-like escape sequences]
[image: Decimal, not octal]
[image: Hex]
[image: Long brackets form]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have already answered the question yourself.
You can escape the backslash with `\\`.
To escape the double quotes you can use single quotes as delimiters.

```
'\\a\\f\\\\\\"'
```