# Append newline in set_by_lua OpenResty

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

Using https://openresty.org/en/ I have the following `nginx.conf` file

I'm trying to put in a newline \n between each request header in the set_by_lua section which I then output to the access.log file.

```sh
http {
    # Trying to see the request headers nicely in the access.log
    # can't seem to get a nice line feed in from lua
    log_format  main  '(ra:)$remote_addr - (ru:)$remote_user (time_local:)[$time_local] (request:)"$request" (status:)$status (bodybytessent:)$body_bytes_sent (http_referer)"$http_referer" (useragent:)"$http_user_agent" (xforward:)"$http_x_forwarded_for" \n(requestheaders:)$request_headers';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {

            set_by_lua $request_headers '
              local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
              local request_headers_all = ""
              for k, v in pairs(h) do
                # Here is the problem - the \n does not work
                # just want to append a line feed to this string
                request_headers_all = request_headers_all .. ""..k..": "..v..";" .. "\n"
              end
              return request_headers_all
            ';

            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

...continued
```

The error is:

2020/06/29 11:36:04 [error] 8204#8204: *25 failed to load inlined Lua code: set_by_lua:6: unfinished string near '"'

This line is the problem:

> request_headers_all = request_headers_all .. ""..k..": "..v..";" .. "\n"

So it is some sort of escaping issue. [Lua ignore Escape Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283122/lua-ignore-escape-sequence) which I'm lost with.

Base OS is Ubuntu 18.04. and I'm trying to get something like this into the access.log file:

[image: output from browser]

instead of this:

```
(ra:)37.152.225.237 - (ru:)- (time_local:)[29/Jun/2020:11:47:46 +0000] (request:)"GET / HTTP/1.1" (status:)200 (bodybytessent:)422 (http_referer)"-" (useragent:)"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0" (xforward:)"-"
(requestheaders:)host: openrestytest836.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com;accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8;upgrade-insecure-requests: 1;cache-control: no-cache;accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.5;user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0;pragma: no-cache;connection: keep-alive;accept-encoding: gzip, deflate;
```

There are a lot of ways of doing this, but I'm curious as to how to get the newline characters into the Lua generated string.

Comment: Have you tried to use `set_by_lua_block`? `set_by_lua` is deprecated. `*_block` directives do not have the escape problem: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#special-escaping-sequences

Comment: BTW, `table.insert` + `table.concat` is way more efficient than repetitive concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @un.def in the comments above who fixed the Lua issue which is now:

```
set_by_lua_block $request_headers {
     local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
     local request_headers_all = ""
     for k, v in pairs(h) do
         request_headers_all = request_headers_all .. ""..k..": "..v.."\n"
     end
     return request_headers_all
}
```

I've not tried the suggested table strategy yet.

From http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

I had to set `esacpe=none` in the log_format also:

```
log_format  main escape=none '(remote_addr:)$remote_addr - (remote_user:)$remote_user (time_local:)[$time_local] (request:)"$request" (status:)$status (bodybytessent:)$body_bytes_sent (http_referer)"$http_referer" (useragent:)"$http_user_agent" (xforward:)"$http_x_forwarded_for" \n(requestheaders:)\n$request_headers';
```

which gives the desired output:
[image]